# Nested stored procedures

Tags: stored-procedures, nested

My goal is: I have three tables dev1, PICK1, rul1, and I need my information interact between them,
An example would be this: according to the results of select rul1 table, took certain lines from dev1 table and insert them into PICK1,

then the lines of the table dev1 have to be updated to avoid getting selected again in the next select from rul1

This is the structure of the tables:

```
dev1 {
[delivery]
[inlist]
[scot]}

rul1{
[group],
[field],
[logical_condition]
[value]}

PICK1 {
[id_delivery]
[group_num]
[lock]}
```

these are some of the values that I have in rul1

```
[group]  [field]    [logical_condition]  [value]
  1         scot        =                   1
  1         inlist      =                   0
  2         scot        =                   2
  2         inlist      =                   0
  3         scot        =                   3
```

Then when I run this stored procedure:

```
BEGIN

DECLARE @ max int, @ count int<br />
SET @ count = 1<br />
SELECT @ max = max ([group]) from rul1 group by [group]

while (@ count <= @ max)<br />
BEGIN<br />
select field + '' + logical_condition + '' + value as [rule] from rul1 where [group]=  @count<br />
SET @ count = (@ count + 1)<br />
END

END
```

I get this results for each group (1, 2, 3):

```
scot = 1
inlist = 0

scot = 2
inlist = 0

scot = 3
```

Now I want to put these results into a string to be part of the clause "where" to select the correct lines from dev1 and insert them into PICK1

then update on dev1, I guess this must be every time when I run the while of the procedure, but I dont know how to nest store procedures or

if this can be completed by other method.

every assistance will be welcome

thank you very much

Comment: **What database** (and which version) are you using? Those things are most often vendor-specific ...